# if (typeof myFunction !== 'function') – why doesn't it work in Safari?

Tags: javascript, safari

I have this code that works in Chrome, but doesn't work as expected in Safari:

```
if (typeof myFunction !== 'function') {

  function myFunction() {
    console.log('myFunction invoked');
  }

  myFunction();

} else {
  console.log('myFunction ALREADY DEFINED o_O!');
}
```

When I run this code in Chrome – it logs "myFunction invoked".

When I run it in Safari – it logs "myFunction ALREADY DEFINED o_O!"

I want to make typeof work in Safari the same as in Chrome. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Probably due to [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)

Comment: Putting a `function` declaration statement in an `if` block is bad practice and not allowed in "strict" mode. The behavior was basically undefined.

Comment: did you test  this : `if (typeof(myFunction) !== 'function' ) { ...`  or`if (typeof(myFunction) === 'undefined' ) { ...`

Comment: Which is a best practice for when I need to define a function inside a template that can be included multiple times inside the code?

Comment: I have your answser but I can't show it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use the below code :

```js
if (typeof myFunction !== 'function') {

  let myFunction = function() {
    console.log('myFunction invoked');
  }

  myFunction();

} else {
  console.log('myFunction ALREADY DEFINED o_O!');
}
```

`let` keyword will fix your problem

Comment: Yay! This one worked for me.